# App stopped working after showing the main activity and show a white screen only after download it from google play

Tags: java, android, google-play

I've uploaded `'app.aab'` file to release on google play store (on internal test environment).
the uploaded finish without any errors. and when I try to download it to my device, the app open with the main activity, ask to approve the permission and then the app stop respond. if I try to re-open the app I see only a white screen.

When I install the APK file on my device (without google play) the app work just fine.
I tried to force close on the app and reopen but nothing seems to help.

This is my `app/build.gredle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.agro_scout.agroscoutfly"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.10'
    compileOnly('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.10')
    implementation ('com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.10')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+'
}
```

I have no idea what the problem is. I am not getting any errors or any crashes.

Please, any help will be great.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: what is the problem with the tags?

Comment: I edited, but [android-studio] tag is only for questions about the IDE itself. For general programming questions, you should use [android] instead.